# Firebug throws error when using Minify and jQuery 1.5.2

Tags: jquery, minify

Im using zend framework [minify view script helper](https://github.com/bubba-h57/zf-helpers)
Everything is doing fine until im adding jQuery 1.5.2 into my minify view helper

```
echo $this->minifyHeadScript()
->prependFile($this->jsUrl('/manage/jquery-1.5.2.min.js'));
```

and then the firebug console throwing this error:

```
missing } after function body
```

but if im using jQuery 1.4.2 version the error is not thrown by firebug console

is there any solution to this? or maybe minify is not compatible for jQuery 1.5.2?

Answer (score 0):

Minifying is the process of reductions of file weight by stripping unwanted white space

This can't make any differce...

try to compress your file here ! with full copied code

http://refresh-sf.com/yui/

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems only occured if im using the min version of the jQuery but not the unpacked version. Seems like this is a bug of minify